# Automated Facebook feed

Tags: feature-request

I think a feature should be created so that just like posts get automatically posted on Twitter, post also on FaceBook.  This automatic posting feature for Facebook should only post questions from here that have a certain number of up-votes, like 5 votes and it get's posted on the Facebook, if there are no votes or there are down-votes than it does not get posted.

Comment: Can't facebook just eat the RSS feed, like Twitter does?

Comment: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=stackislam <-- the rss feed for the twitter account.